# How to handle Url encoding in HttpListenerRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, httplistenerrequest

I'm building a simple server that uses `HttpListener` to process requests.  The query string parameters I send to it are url encoded if necessary.  For example, to send the Kanji string `"尺八"`, the encoding is `"%E5%B0%BA%E5%85%AB"`.

My sample url, then is `"/?q=%E5%B0%BA%E5%85%AB"`.

In my context callback, I have:

```
HttpListenerContext context = Listener.EndGetContext();
string rawUrl = context.Request.RawUrl;
string query = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
```

Checking the results, I get:

```
rawUrl = "/?q=%E5%B0%BA%E5%85%AB" 
query = "å°ºå…«"
```

But if I look at `context.Request.Url`, I get `{http://localhost:8080/?q=尺八}`.

It looks like the query string in `context.Request.QueryString` is being decoded using some encoding other than UTF-8.

My workaround is to ignore `context.Request.QueryString` and create my own by doing this:

```
var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(context.Request.Url.Query);
```

That gives me the correct value, but it seems like something of a hack.

Is there any way to tell the `HttpListener` (or the context, or the request) to interpret the query string as UTF-8, which I think is the standard anyway?  Or should I just live with this workaround?

Comment: You sure have some nice query strings :D

Comment: Downvoter? It's customary to provide an explanatory comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the code, it relies on ContentEncoding being set to UTF8.  Here is the snipit from the QueryString property of HttpListenerRequest:

```
public NameValueCollection QueryString
{
    get
    {
        NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        Helpers.FillFromString(nvc, this.Url.Query, true, this.ContentEncoding);
        return nvc;
    }
}
```

Since there is no way to modify the ContentEncoding property your stuck with your 'hack'.  Anyway, I think your use of HttpUtility.ParseQueryString is likely going to serve you the best.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that. I wonder if this is a bug (I think the RFC says that Url encoding is UTF-8) or if it's just a hole in the standard. Still, it seems odd that the `Url` property would be right, but the `QueryString` property would be wrong.

Comment: Correct it is a bug (and not the only one).  the ContentEncoding header should only be used for the body of the HTTP request, not the URL.  Even then it's somewhat ambiguous as to its meaning due to poor specifications/standards.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `System.Web.HttpUtility`

```
 string query = "d=bla bla bla";
 string encoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode( query, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 );
```

Learn more https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility(v=vs.110).aspx